# Python process pool isnt creating expected numberof processes

Tags: python, dictionary, process, pool, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to write a simple program using python's pool module. Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ApplyResult
import time
import os

def unwrap_self_f(arg, **kwarg):
  print 'inside unwrap_self_f'
  return C().f(arg, **kwarg)

class C:
  def f(self, name):
    return 'Inside f..Process id :' + str(os.getpid())

  def run(self):
    print 'Reached inside run..'
    print 'main process id ..', os.getpid()
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    names = ['frank', 'justin', 'osi', 'thomas']        
    print pool.map(unwrap_self_f, names, 1)               

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print 'Starting....'
   c = C()
   print 'Running....'
   c.run()
```

When I run this program, I was expecting to see 4 different process ids being printed, one for each child process that was created. The chunksize that I have selected is 1, so that each item in the list goes to a separate process.

However the process id being printed is the same. I get the below output:

```
Starting....
Running....
Reached inside run..
main process id .. 1284
['Inside f..Process id :6872', 'Inside f..Process id :6872', 'Inside f..Process id :6872', 'Inside f..Process  id :6872']
```

Am I getting somewhere wrong here. Please can anyone shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me under OS X. So, what OS are you using, and how many cores does your machine have?

Comment: For me it works *sometimes* (ubuntu 12.04.5). After adding `time.sleep(1)` in the worker  function, I get different ids.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map Ref the docs, it says "The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer." I guess there's no guarantee that specifying the chunksize will work - what happens if you don't specify it at all?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822512/chunksize-parameter-in-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-map  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264435/do-multiprocessing-pools-give-every-process-the-same-number-of-tasks-or-are-the

Comment: Thanks to all for their help. Following @hitzg comment. I added some time delay in the f method and increased the passed list. I was able to see different ids. I think python decides to handover tasks to different processes on their availability.